# Playing an external link on the Spotify player

Tags: spotify

I've been trying to get the Spotify player to play something from a URL.

```
var sp = getSpotifyApi(1);
var models = sp.require('sp://import/scripts/api/models');

var t = models.Link.fromURL("http://some link here.mp3");
models.player.play(t);
```

Is this even possible? Am I using Link.fromURL correctly? Every time I run it, the console seems to suggest fromURL doesn't exist.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The Spotify Apps API can only play tracks sourced from a Spotify URI, like this:

```
var t = models.Link.fromURL("spotify:track:4QXxA6ixE222Ely7fAeopM");
models.player.play(t);
```

All other URLs are unsupported.

Comment: So theoretically, if I was using libspotify to call songs and manipulating the audio buffer of those songs (changing pitch, bpm, etc), I can't return the new song to the Spotify client. I wonder - HTML5 audio isn't enabled in the Spotify client, but flash is. Maybe I can use that as a work around?

Comment: Well, doing what you're doing with libSpotify is against our terms and conditions and Flash isn't supported in Apps API apps — it may *work*, but getting it public is a different matter I'm afraid.